# UDP socket in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am trying to connect to an UDP socket on another computer using the UDP socket of node.js and I am getting the following error:

```
bind EADDRNOTAVAIL192.168.1.50;12345
```

I am using the following code:

```
var port = 12345;
   var host = "192.168.1.50";
   var sock = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
   sock.on("listening", function () {
       console.log("server listening ");
    });

    sock.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("server error:\n" + err.stack);
        sock.close();
    });

    //start the UDP server with the radar port 12345
    sock.bind(port, host);
```

any help?

thanks

Comment: is that IP the remote or local IP address?

Comment: EADDRNOTAVAIL generally means that either port or ip address is not available. And 192.168.1.50 is your system ip address ? host should be your local address.

Comment: maybe i didn't get it right - i am trying to build a UDP client in node.js which will receive messages from the UDP server on a different computer (the server IP is 192.168.1.50 and he is sending on port 12345). what am i doing wrong?

Comment: yes, the code you wrote is for UDP server that listens on port 12345.

Comment: `bind` is for the local address. You first `bind` the local IP/Port, then you `sendto` the remote IP/Port.

Comment: so, why am i getting the error? in the stack trace i can see the exception is thrown from process._tickCallback(node.js:358:17)

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind to the remote server address! It doesn't matter what your server ip is, you should bind to one of your local interfaces. If you want to bind on all local interfaces, just bind like following:

```
 sock.bind(port);
```

Comment: then how can i create a client which is waiting for a udp dadagram from a specific server? (the code in the server is already written and won't be changed. he is sending the data on port 12345 and the IP i gave)

Comment: @EfratCohen, you can't. You will listen for all datagrams sent to this IP:port. If the datagram is not from someone you are interested in, you can skip it.

Answer (score 1):

You can send UDP datagrams in the following way (Sample code)

```
var dgram = require('dgram');

var PORT = 12345;
var HOST = '192.168.1.50';
var message = new Buffer('Pinging');

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
client.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, HOST, function(err, bytes) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('UDP message sent to ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
   client.close();
});
```

Reference: http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-udp-server-and-client-example.html

Comment: thanks for the help but, i don't need to send messages, only to receive them from IP 192.168.1.50 on port 12345

Comment: FYI: "(node:15284) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead." I found https://gist.github.com/sid24rane/6e6698e93360f2694e310dd347a2e2eb helpful.