# Node.js UDP unicast

Tags: javascript, udp, unicast

I've been asked to write a client/server model using Node.js. The communication must use UDP unicast. I've already written some client/server code using UDP multicast, but never unicast. And so far I've not found any good explanation on the difference and, most important, how to implement this using Node.js. Is it very different from a code transferring data in multicast?

Comment: There is nothing special about [unicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast). It's just a connection to a single peer, i.e. more of the normal case. Multicast is actually the special one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDP socket in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696648/udp-socket-in-node-js), [How to send udp packages using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709577/how-to-send-udp-packages-using-nodejs)

Comment: Unicast is the normal way to communicate in both TCP and UDP.